# IONIC Tabs navbar is appears in subpages why?

Tags: css, html, ionic2, bootstrap-4

> this is my tabs navbar this is overlapping on my other subpages also

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar hideBackButton="true">
    <span class="hdr-clr">Winkrr</span>
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button icon-only>
        <ion-icon style="color:#ed145b;" name="ios-search"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only>
        <ion-icon style="color:#ed145b;" name="ios-notifications-outline"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only>
        <ion-icon style="color:#ed145b;" name="ios-contact-outline"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-tabs tabsPlacement="top" tabsHideOnSubPages="true" primary>
  <ion-tab tabIcon="md-globe" [root]="tab1Root"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabIcon="stats" [root]="tab2Root"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

> this is my sub page navbar

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar hide-tabs>
    <ion-title>personal-chat</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

> this is how i navigate

```
  onContact(){
    this.navCtrl.push(PersonalChatPage);
  }
```

> I have used the tabs for single page in ionic 2. I have use the ion navbar for tabs page which is common for two tabs.
>   But the same navbar appears on subpages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coult try to set the config in you app.module.ts like this:

```
 imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
            // Tabs config
            tabsHideOnSubPages: true,
            ...
        })
    ]
```

Comment: I did same, after doing that i successfully hide the tabs on subpages. But the issue is - i want to hide the navbar(header) for subpages.

Comment: If you dont want a header on subpages remove it from their html file. Be sure on ion-content is in your html of your subpage. If that doesnt work try to work with .root(Subpage)